# How to make and efficiently run "void" PySpark user defined function (UDF) that returns nothing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

Given the available methods for specifying user defined functions in PySpark:

- Row-at-a-time native PySpark UDFs
- Pandas UDFs that make use of Apache Arrow

How could one create and run on a dataframe a user defined function that does not return anything without having to create a new column?

Example: say you wanted to parallelize loading a dataframe column into some external persistence store. I.e. instead of writing the whole dataframe to HDFS, use one field as a key and another as a value for transfer row-by-row into a blob store such as s3.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you wouldn't use `UDF` at all. There unsuitable for the task for a number of reasons. Instead you just use [`foreach`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach.html)

> `foreach(f)`
>
> Applies the f function to all Row of this DataFrame.

or [`foreachPartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html)

> `foreachPartition(f)`
>
> Applies the f function to each partition of this DataFrame.

Comment: Since this is PySpark, this will come at the cost of serializing each row from Java workers to Python workers no? Wouldn't it be better to do this via a Pandas UDF with arrow if possible to avoid this overhead?